# Redirect WooCommerce shop page to a single product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I am setting up a shop section of my website in WooCommerce.

I only have 1 product to sell, so therefore when my users click the 'store' option from my main menu I want it to take them straight to that specific product page where they can see an image of the product,a full description and add it to their basket. 
I don't want them to have to navigate to a conventional 'store' page beforehand because 1 only have 1 product but WooCommerce won't let me set it up this way. It should be as simple as defining a custom URL but it appears not.

Any ideas as to how I can get around this? Thanks

Comment: Redirect: using "Redirect plugin" or simple javascript `window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";`

Comment: But why you pu the link for shop page just use directly the product url in menu

Comment: Thats great, thanks. I downloaded the 'redirection' plugin and set it to re-direct from store to a custom URL. Very easy to set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use any Redirect plugin, redirect yourdomain/shop to yourdomain/specific-product-page.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a custom link to the product page in your main menu, and name the link "Shop".

Answer (score 0):

You could add a redirect to *the_post* hook with the *product_id* of the product in question to your themes/child themes *functions.php* file like this:

```
function stackoverflow_redirect_back_from_shop(){
    if( is_shop() ){
        $url = get_permalink( $product_id );
        wp_redirect($url);
    }
}

add_action('the_post', 'stackoverflow_redirect_back_from_shop');
```

Comment: This worked for me except I had to use this action `add_action('template_redirect', 'stackoverflow_redirect_back_from_shop');`